# Recursive calling overloaded c++ functions

Tags: c++, recursion, sfinae

I have few custom types that will be used as distinct arguments for functions:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};
struct E {};
```

There are also a number of functions that returns functor wrappers:

```
template <typename H>
auto foo (H h,
  enable_if_t<is_same<typename result_of<H(A)>::type, bool>::value>* = 0)
{
  return [h] (B x) { return h (A {}); };
}
```

This thing converts H (A) functor into G (B) functor, that converts input argument B->A (not implemented here for simplicity) and calls H with A.

I have the similar convertors C->B, D->C, E->D:

```
template <typename H>
auto foo (H h,
  enable_if_t<is_same<typename result_of<H(B)>::type, bool>::value>* = 0)
{
  return [h] (C x) { return h (B {}); };
}

template <typename H>
auto foo (H h,
  enable_if_t<is_same<typename result_of<H(C)>::type, bool>::value>* = 0)
{
  return [h] (D x) { return h (C {}); };
}

template <typename H>
auto foo (H h,
  enable_if_t<is_same<typename result_of<H(D)>::type, bool>::value>* = 0)
{
  return [h] (E x) { return h (D {}); };
}
```

Now I can call foo 4 times and will get the functor that gets argument of type "E", and finally calls inner handler with argument "A":

```
auto inner_handler = [] (A) -> bool { return false; };
auto f = foo (foo (foo (foo ( inner_handler ))));
f (E {});
```

What I want is to implement call_until function that would call "foo" overloads recursively until the argument type of resulting functor became T.

Let's say the path of convertors from A to E always exists and is exactly one. In other words I'd like the expression

```
auto f = call_until<E> ( inner_handler );
```

work exactly as

```
auto f = foo (foo (foo (foo ( inner_handler ))));
```

I'm starting from something like:

```
template <typename Stop, typename Handler, typename Result>
struct call_until_helper
{
  Handler handler_;
  call_until_helper (Handler h) : handler (h) {}
};

template <typename Stop, typename Handler>
call_until_helper<Stop, Handler,
  typename boost::function_traits<Handler>::result_type>
call_until (Handler handler)
{
  return call_until_helper<Stop, Handler,
    typename boost::function_traits<Handler>::result_type> (handler);
}
```

But I got compile errors and kinda stuck at this point. I need some ideas how to implement this.

The code online: http://ideone.com/ZRFxnw

Comment: Try to use `->` to mean "takes arguments from the left hand side, and returns the right hand side", as this matches more conventional functional notation.  So there is an overload `foo:` `H:A->bool` `->` `G:B->bool`.  To make your code cleaner, can you replace `result_of` with `result_of_t`?  If your compiler doesn't have it, write one `template<class Sig>using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;`.  Less noise is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proximate problem is that `function_traits` expects a function type, not a lambda type.  To determine this, simply find the error, extract the statement that caused it, and peel back the types and pass them in directly.

```
boost::function_traits< decltype( inner_handler ) >::result_type b = false;
```

fails to compile.  I then checked the docs, and yes, it expects a function type, not a lambda.  Lambdas are not functions.

---

This is a sketch of a solution to a problem near your actual problem.  The syntax differs a bit, as I am lazy.

Here is `fooify`.  It represents the entire overload set of `foo` in a single object:

```
struct fooify {
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const{
    return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

This is a helper type that recursively applies an action to an input until a test is passed:

```
template<class Action, template<class...>class test, class Arg, class=void>
struct repeat_until_helper {
  using action_result = result_of_t< Action&(Arg) >;
  auto operator()(Action&& action, Arg&&arg)const {
    return repeat_until_helper<Action, test, action_result>{}(
      std::forward<Action>(action),
      action( std::forward<Arg>(arg) )
    );
  }
};
template<class Action, template<class...>class test, class Arg>
struct repeat_until_helper< Action, test, Arg,
  std::enable_if_t< test<Arg>{} >
> {
  auto operator()(Action&& action, Arg&&arg)const {
    return std::forward<Arg>(arg);
  }
};
```

This is a function that uses the above helper, so we only need to pass in one type (the test), and the rest are deduced:

```
template<template<class...>class test, class Action, class Arg>
auto repeat_until( Action&& action, Arg&& arg) {
    return repeat_until_helper< Action, test, Arg >{}( std::forward<Action>(action), std::forward<Arg>(arg) );
}
```

Here is a test for a type being called with an `E` rvalue:

```
template<class X, class=void>
struct can_be_called_with_E:std::false_type{};
template<class X>
struct can_be_called_with_E<X,
    decltype(
        void(
            std::declval<X>()(std::declval<E>())
        )
    )
>:std::true_type{};
```

And we are done.  The syntax differs, but that is just a bit of work to tidy up.

[live example](http://ideone.com/OH2oLn)

Comment: Your code works fine and can be easily ported for c++11. However I meat difficulties when tried to port it to c++03 (using boost meta libraries, type traits, etc). The particular problem is unability to define return type of "fooify" functor for the compiler. Here is my best attempt to port it to c++03: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b40e6443be9c9e Unfortunatly it does not compile :)

Comment: @NikkiChumakov yes, overload set objects in C++03 are awkward to write.  You can replace `Action` with a hardcoded call to `foo` in `repeat_until_helper` (and call it `repeat_foo_until_helper`).  But `action_result` ends up being a mess as you lack `decltype` or anything equivalent, and you lack lists of types to make a manual limited `decltype` viable.

Comment: Finally I was able to code C++03 version by manually defining foo's return result traits as "template <class H> struct foo_traits<H, typename enable_if<is_same<typename result_of<H(Arg)>::type, bool>>::type" for each Arg in [A,B,C,D,E]. And I used these traits in footify class. It's ugly but works somehow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nikki btw, you do know you can have a template that writes `can_be_called_with_E` from `E`?  `template<class E, class X,class=void> struct helper:std::false_type{}; template<class E, class X>struct helper<X,decltype(void(std::declval<X>()(std::declval<E>()))>:std::true_type{};` then `template<class E>struct can_be_called_with{ template<class X> struct test: helper<E,X>{}; };`  Not useful in C++03 but..

Comment: Boost has "result_of" facility that supports result resolving method defined in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1454.html So I just used it. I need to define nested "result" template classes in all my fuctional objects, but as I have to write c++03 compatible code, I usually do it anyway. Here is the code paste: http://codepad.org/y2kDHnM3 . And here is the full c++03 port just for record: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77671d38349920da